# Retrieve client ip address in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get with a simple SQL statement the IP address of the client. I do not want to use PHP or other techniques. Only pure SQL. When I use

```
SELECT USER();
```

I get

```
dbouser@host.i.do.not.care.of
```

When I use

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

I get

```
dbouser@%
```

But how do I get the plain IP? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You will only get the IP address of the client process communicating with MySQL. Assuming this is what you want:

```
select host from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

Will give you the host name (or IP address if name resolution is not enabled, which it is usually not) connecting to the mysql server on the current connection.

Comment: Thanks MarkR for the fast answer. Unfortunately I am working on a managed server with limited permissions. I am not allowed to access 'information_schema.processlist'.

Comment: information_schema.processlist does not require privileges to access. They must be using either a hacked or very old version of MySQL.

Answer (score 10):

To get the IP address only without the port number.

`select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1) as 'ip' from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();`

Answer (score 5):

@mvf - instead of reverse you could do:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1) AS ip;
```

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(USER()),'@',1)) as ip;
SELECT SUBSTRING(USER(), LOCATE('@', USER())+1) as ip;
```

Comment: user() function is a nice solution too.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use this to get IP address from the client and then insert it into the table
`$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`;