# How can I find the IP address of the current user's connection in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ip, ip-address

Before you answer "use current_user()", which does work for many cases, or "use user()", which really doesn't work, please read the following...

I am attempting to create a view on a table which limits user access to certain rows within the table, controlled by the IP address from which the user connects.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
create table testtable (
  `RowID` bigint not null auto_increment,
  `owner` varchar(64),
  `key` varchar(64),
  `val` varchar(64),
  primary key (`RowID`)
);
create view testview (
  `RowID`,
  `owner`,
  `key`,
  `val`
) as select
  `testtable`.`RowID` as `RowID`,
  `testtable`.`owner` as `owner`,
  `testtable`.`key` as `key`,
  `testtable`.`val` as `val`
from testtable
where (testtable.owner = substring_index(current_user(), '@', -1));

create user 'testuser'@'192.168.3.30' identified by 'testpass';
grant select, insert, update, delete on testview to 'testuser'@'192.168.3.30';
```

Now the theory is that I should be able to log in as testuser from the host 192.168.3.30 and do something like `select * from testview` and get the proper subset of testtable that applies to me.

The above does not work.  The reason it doesn't work is that `current_user()` returns the view's *definer* by default, resulting in no data, or (worse) the wrong data, depending on who the definer was.  If I want `current_user()` to return the *invoking* user, I need to create the view with a `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` clause, which also limits the security privileges to those of the invoking user, thus defeating the original purpose of the code.

I would love to use `user()`, but unfortunately, that almost always returns the hostname/domain instead of the IP address.

Side note, in case it's not clear:  Getting the IP address in PHP (or Ruby, or perl, or whatever) is not useful in this case.  I'm setting up a bit of database security, so relying on the client is obviously inadequate.  I need the IP address in the SQL.

For the curious looking for ideas/reference/context:

For reference, I got the idea for this nifty security trick from [here](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/), but they're using the username instead of the IP address, which would make this much easier.  In my case, I'm trying to set up a database of hosts which is partially updated from the hosts themselves.  I don't want to set up a different user for each host, but I do want each host to be able to update its own records (of filesystems, fan speeds, temperatures, and so on).

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question? It's written out well and it's clear the author has done their research?

Comment: `show processlist` will list the user/ip stuff, but there doesn't seem to be a way to filter it by a particular user. Don't think there's any other function/query that would return this data

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6263482/797303)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve client ip address in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263453/retrieve-client-ip-address-in-mysql)

Comment: @Darhazer:  That solution does not work without changing the mysqld invocation (which I may eventually do, but I'd like a solution that works in the general case).  information_schema.processlist gives me the host name by default, not the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to leave a question unanswered...

It appears that there is no way to do this without globally modifying the behavior of mysqld (by disabling name resolution entirely), which obviously has consequences in other areas.

Fortunately, a different option is to create a "stub" program, accessed via SSH, which accepts the data from the client, checks the IP address, and passes the (possibly-modified) data on to the database.  Of course, this uses SSH validation instead of a database account and introduces another layer of complexity.  It also requires that you have shell-level access to a server which can act as the go-between.  On the plus side, it does arguably provide better security (encryption over the line and superior authentication) if the stub is implemented properly.

Comment: You can connect to MySQL over SSL/TLS using whatever means of authentication you like... so those 'advantages' of SSH aren't genuine; I'd also suggest that, whilst this workaround may suit your needs, it doesn't really answer the question (how to determine the MySQL client IP - in this case it should discover the address of the SSH server).

Comment: @eggyal: you are correct on all points.  Unfortunately, there appears to be no real answer to the original question.  In other words, as stated, it cannot be done.  I figured posting a workaround was better than nothing.  The main advantage of the ssh workaround is that it works.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the `mysqld` process, you could launch it with the [`--skip-name-resolve`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve) option; then `SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1)` would give you the current user's IP address.

Comment: That's what I was going to say.

Comment: OK, that's very good to know.  But what if I don't have control over the mysqld process, or I want to be able to use host names in my grant tables (for other unrelated users, for example)?