# Getting ip address using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, ip-address

In MySQL query:

```
SELECT host
FROM information_schema.processlist
WHERE ID = connection_id( )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The result of ^ this query is: `localhost`.

```
SELECT @@hostname;
```

The result of ^ this query is: `localhost`.

But I need  to get ipaddress like `192.168.1.2`.

**Question:** *How to get this result using mysql query?*

Comment: You cannot do that with mysql if your name resolving is working. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10574565/986959)

Comment: @c vijila Are you succeeded on getting the ip address there yet instead of "localhost"? Would be great if you update us if something works there.

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712867/how-to-get-the-ip-address-mysql/26713089#26713089

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the IP address only without the port number.

```
 Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1) as 'ip' 
 From information_schema.processlist 
 WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

Comment: This will also resolve the name "localhost" if you are running it in local machine. Is there any idea to get the IP?

Comment: WARNING:  The above query is misleading and does not yield the expected results and is not reliable.
if you are logging into the mysql server remotely, the IP address returned is from the server you are connecting from.
 If you are logged into the database server itself, the result is 'localhost', not an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The query
`select host from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();`

Will give you the host name .You will get  IP address( like `192.168.1.2.`) if name resolution is not enabled, which it is usually not.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950556) and is great split function you can rewrite it like this :

```
Select user,CONCAT(Split_fn(host, "-", 2),'.',Split_fn(host, "-", 3),'.',Split_fn(host, "-", 4),'.',Split_fn(Split_fn(host, "-", 5),".",1)) as Ip_Address from information_schema.PROCESSLIST where ID = CONNECTION_ID()
```

Comment: This always gives me an error. Split_fn is no default MySQL function... In my case, the host is `localhost:52321`, so it cannot be split at any '-' or '.' characters.

Answer (score -1):

I found that many MySQL servers use the [`BIND_ADDRESS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address) global variable. This variable returns the IP address(es) that the server listens to. However, in my tests, this value was usually "127.0.0.1".

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'HOSTNAME';     -- Returns: MyHostName
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'BIND_ADDRESS'; -- Returns: 127.0.0.1
```

Alternative Syntax:

```sql
SELECT @@hostname, @@bind_address;  -- Returns: MyHostName, 127.0.0.1
```

**Note:**

This is not a bulletproof solution. Depending on server configuration, the key `BIND_ADDRESS` (or `@@bind_address`) can also return the value `*`.

Comment: depending on server configuration Value is "*" for key "bind_address".

Comment: @immobiluser thanks for that info. I've added a note about this behavior to the answer above.

Answer (score -7):

Please tell me whether you need to get IP from visitor of the site, or something else. If you just need IP of the visitor, you could use php remote_addr function.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Is it something like a table where IP adresses are stored? I think that your query is looking for host, not for IP. But I am not sure if I understood you properly.

Comment: What has PHP to do with MySQL's client IP? Even - why PHP?

Comment: In the past I used php in order to get IP address. I did not understand question properly.

Comment: Maybe select * from this table and see which column contains IP address?

Comment: Besides being the wrong technology, this also gives you the IP address of **the users browser**, not a server address