# How to get the IP address [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, ip-address

How can I get the IP address of mysql server running in the localhost machine?

The following query returns 'localhost' because of name resolution.

```
   Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1) as 'ip' 
   From information_schema.processlist 
   WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

So what needs to be done to not take the name resolution into consideration or is there any other way of getting the IP address?

Thanks

Comment: [More information about 'localhost'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for my knowledge you can't directly fetch the ip address of your localhost. But mysql has utitlity which is present in directory `mysql\bin` whose execution file name is `resolveip` for that you can execute it like this.

```
resolveip localhost
```

In command prompt please give this by pointing your command prompt path to bin directory.
For further detail about resolveip [click me!!!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resolveip.html)

It will return text output as like this

`IP address of localhost is 127.0.0.1`

This function is two way return i.e. Instead of resolved name if you give ip address like this

```
resolveip 127.0.0.1
```

It will return text output as like this

`Host name of 127.0.0.1 is mypc.local, localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
./resolveip localhost
```

In case you are using XAMPP and cannot call **resolveip** directly.
Make sure you are inside the bin folder.